# Why can assignment from one type to the same need checking?

Tags: java, static-analysis

I'm running IntelliJ's Code Analyzer (IntelliJ 11.1.4) on a class and am getting this warning:

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List '

The code it complains about is:

```
List<String> targetDocumentIds = pepperWorkflowInstance.getTargetDocumentIds();
```

For reference:

```
public class PepperWorkflowInstance<T extends PepperWorkflowInstanceData> implements Serializable {

   private List<String>            targetDocumentIds = new ArrayList<String>();
   ...
   public List<String> getTargetDocumentIds() {
      return targetDocumentIds;
   }
   ...
}
```

So the types match... so why would I need to 'check' the assignment?

Comment: What type is `targetDocumentIds` from `pepperWorkflowInstance` instance?

Comment: Just realized this is a IntelliJ warning, not JVM. What version of IntelliJ do you have?

Comment: Made edits to address comments

Comment: Do not discard a bug in Idea

Comment: @Luciano I haven't, but I'd like to confirm that I'm not missing something in Java, first

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `pepperWorkflowInstance` has parameter:

```
pepperWorkflowInstance = new PepperWorkflowInstance<SomeClass>();
```

See [IDEA-6254](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-6254).

Answer (score 0):

If the pepperWorkflowInstance is of super class where raw type is used as return type, 
then that may generate that message.

Example.

```
class A{
    public List getTargetDocumentIds(){
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public List<String> getTargetDocumentIds(){
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        List<String> targetDocumentIds = a.getTargetDocumentIds(); 
        // above produces compiler type safety warning                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that applies to my situation... good info though.